# FadeIn is not giving proper timing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 divs I want to show each of them 1 sec apart. But that does not seem to happen . What is actually happening in the loop. Please explain!!Currently all the divs appear together. But i want to show them one at a time.
I want the second DIV to appear after the first div has appeared.

http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonrufus/TUL6s/

```
var blockOne = $('#block1');
blockInner = blockOne.find('.inner-block');
blockInner.fadeOut();

blockInner.each(function (index, value) {
    time = 2000+(index*5000);  <- just expermenting
    $(this).fadeIn(time);
    console.log(time)
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try chaining and use a callback function to handle each time the fadeIn of the next element

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/TUL6s/1/

```
var blockOne = $('#block1');
blockInner = blockOne.find('.inner-block');

var fadeNextIn = function(){
    if($(this).next()){
        $(this).next().fadeIn(1000,fadeNextIn);
    }
}

blockInner.fadeOut('slow')
          .first().fadeIn(1000,fadeNextIn);
```

Comment: hello is callback the only way??

Comment: It's the proper way in Javascript. And it's easier if you get the hang of it.

Comment: No problem. Try to see some examples with jQuery, there are many tutorials on the web to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `delay` if its not the first div:

```
blockInner.each(function (index, value) {
    $(this).delay(index > 0 ? 2000*index : 0).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TUL6s/5/